# How do I check if a column is calculated from other columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, calculated-columns

my data frame is named daily_activity and the columns are TotalDistance, ActiveDistance, ModeratelyActiveDistance, LightActiveDistance, and SedentaryActiveDistance

```
if daily_activity['TotalDistance'] == daily_activity['ActiveDistance'] + daily_activity['ModeratelyActiveDistance'] + daily_activity['LightActiveDistance'] + daily_activity['SedentaryActiveDistance']:
  print('True')
else:
  print('False')
```

I keep getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
daily_activity['TotalDistance'] == daily_activity['ActiveDistance'] + daily_activity['ModeratelyActiveDistance'] + daily_activity['LightActiveDistance'] + daily_activity['SedentaryActiveDistance']
```

returns a series of `True`, `False` values based on matches.

Use `all()` on the series to see if every value is `True` like:

```
if (daily_activity['TotalDistance'] == daily_activity['ActiveDistance'] + daily_activity['ModeratelyActiveDistance'] + daily_activity['LightActiveDistance'] + daily_activity['SedentaryActiveDistance']).all():
   print('True')
else:
   print('False')
```

Comment: KeyError: 'ActiveDistance'
I got the above error using the .all()

Comment: @Black_IG It means there is no column called 'ActiveDistance' in your data frame.